# SQL Subtraction one by one

Tags: mysql, sql

I was thinking of subtracting digits one by one but didn't find a way to implement it after a big effort.

**Row 1:** 100211210

**Row 2:** 100010220

**Result:** 000201010

And the result has to be non-negative.

Comment: Hi! How many number do you have? Do you want to subtract always two number? And if the result is negative, than the select have to give back 0?

Comment: @LászlóTóth Hello, Yes but long numbers.

Comment: Two long number? How long is a number? 20 character, 2000 character?

Comment: @LászlóTóth `1 - 2 = | -1 | = 1` OR `0 - 2 = | -2 | = 2`

Comment: @LászlóTóth About 70 or 80 characters

Comment: The two string are the same length?

Comment: Why do you want to use SQL for this? I'd use a programing language instead.

Comment: @LászlóTóth Yes, (`1nth-1nth` , `2nth-2nth`, `3nth-3nth`, ...)

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, These digits are extracted from images to find similar images like Google Search by image, There are millions of images and the loop in programming languages has to check every record and it makes it a long process to find similar results...

Comment: Ah, okay. So you'll have to write a stored procedure to loop through the strings' characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Select SUBSTR(t1.row,1,1)-(t2.row,1, 1)|| SUBSTR(t1.row,2,2)-SUBSTR(t2.row,2, 2)||... so on from table t1 where t1.row NOT IN (Select row in table t2);`

This will check in the same table if the row exists then it will skip if not subtract digit by digit or you can use loop in pl/sql by declaring values for substr as i,j for both and then subtracting.

Comment: Hello, nth digit from the first row and nth digit from the second one, `1nth digit - 1nth digit` , `2nth digit - 2nth digit` , ...

Comment: Is it impossible to tell the query to do the process automatically without writing every nth-digit?

Comment: perhaps you surely require declared value and loop running to increment the values until last digit for this declaration and looping you need procedure or function or anonymous block meaning `Declare i,j; i:=0,j:=0; BEGIN LOOP  SELECT SUBSTR(t1.row,i,j) -SUBSTR(t2,row,i,j)  from .... i:=i+1;j:=j+1; EXIT WHEN i=length(t1.row)... EnD LOOP; ` somewhat like this plsql can help if you want auto increment

Answer (score 0):

```
select GROUP_CONCAT(CAST(ABS(substring('123456782',c.count,1)-substring('323456789',c.count,1)) AS CHAR) separator '')
from (select c1.1*10+c2.1 count from (select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9 union all select 0) c1,
(select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9 union all select 0) c2 order by count) c
where c.count>0 and c.count<=length('123456782')
```

2 string is the same length, and the last parameter is the lenght of the strings

Comment: Please take a look at the result in my question, Digit by Digit. not completely,